# ObjectAnimator works on emulator but not phone

Tags: android, animation

I'm using ObjectAnimator to do some animation. 
It works perfect on Emulator Nexus 5X API 28 Android 9.0.
When I tray running the app on my Galaxy S5 Android 6, and Galaxy Note 4 Android 6, It doesn't work.

Here is the code I'm using

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/Text"
        android:text="Start"
        android:onClick="start"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.Text);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Path myPath = new Path();
            myPath.addCircle(1, 1, 70, Path.Direction.CW);
            myAnima = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(text, View.X, View.Y, myPath);
            myAnima.setDuration(4000);
            myAnima.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            myAnima.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            myAnima.start();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "your Device not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

does anyone have any idea why ?

Comment: `"It doesn't work"` - i love such problem descriptions - does it crash or something? what do you see on the `logcat`?

Comment: @pskink I don't see any errors and it doesn't crash .

Comment: does `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(text, View.TRANSLATION_X, 0, 300)` work? if so, google for `ObjectAnimator Path bug` for more infoe

Comment: @pskink Yes it does.

Comment: then write your own `PathAnimator` that uses  `ValueAnimator` and sets the `View.X` and `View.Y` in the listener

Comment: @pskink OK, thanks for helping :) .